# Error Delete contact when contact count of the Account is only 1

Tags: apex, trigger

How to display error when deleting contact where count of contact of the account is 1.

This is my but its not working

```
trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (before delete, after delete) {

 if(Trigger.isDelete){
      system.debug(trigger.old);
     List<Id> accountId = new List<Id>();
      for(Contact cont: trigger.old){
        if(cont.AccountId != NULL ){
            accountId.add(cont.AccountId);
        }
    }
     system.debug(accountId);
     List<Contact> con = [Select id From Contact Where AccountId IN : accountId];
     List<Contact> deletecon = new List<Contact>();
     try{
         if(con.size() < 1){
             for(Contact cont: con){
                 deletecon.add(cont);
             }
             delete deletecon;
         }   
     }catch(DMLException e){
         system.debug('value wrong');
          for(Contact cont: con){
                cont.AddError('Please');
             }
     }
    
}
```

}

I tried doing it like this but of no luck

```
trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (before delete, after delete) {

 if(Trigger.isDelete){
      system.debug(trigger.old);
     List<Id> accountId = new List<Id>();
      for(Contact cont: trigger.old){
        if(cont.AccountId != NULL ){
            accountId.add(cont.AccountId);
        }
    }
     system.debug(accountId);
     List<Contact> con = [Select id From Contact Where AccountId IN : accountId];

         if(con.size() == 1){
             for(Contact cont: con){
                 cont.AddError('Please error');
             }
             
         }   
 
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic was close, but you need to bulkify your code. The following trigger should do what you'd like it to do, although if there's more than one contact on the same account and they're all deleted at once, all records will display the error.

```
trigger ContactTrigger on Contact (after delete) {
    // Aggregate account ids //
    Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Contact record: Trigger.old) {
        accountIds.add(record.AccountId);
    }
    accountIds.remove(null);
    // Query for remaining contacts //
    accountIds.removeAll(
        new Map<Id, AggregateResult>(
            [SELECT AccountId Id FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :accountIds GROUP BY AccountId]
        ).keySet()
    );
    // Error out contacts that would be the last remaining contact for the account //
    for(Contact record: Trigger.old) {
        if(accountIds.contains(record.AccountId)) {
            record.addError('You cannot delete the last contact for an account.');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much